# A Mixin that doesn't share state

Tags: javascript, state, delegation

I'm just starting to grasp how JavaScript works w/ Behavioral Delegation/Composition/Mixins etc, and I think its pretty neat. 
However when I create a new object using this pattern. I just noticed 
that both of them share the same 'items' prop. value. We all know that JS has really no Class at all. I'm just wondering, how can I implement the correct way of this design pattern w/o using any class, also addressing that shared state between different 'Players'. Thanks.

```
var Player = {
 init: function(name, level) {
  this.name = name
  this.level = level
 },
 getLevel: function() {
  return this.level
 }
}

var Inventory = {
 items: ['Wooden Sword', 'Small Potion', ...],
 addItem: function(item) {
  this.items.push(item)
 },
 removeItem: function(item) {
  var i = this.items.indexOf(item)
  if (i === -1) return
  this.items.splice(i, 1)
 }
}

// ..

var mario = Object.assign(Object.create(Player), Inventory)
mario.init('Mario', 1)
mario.addItem('Nice hat')
mario.items // ['Wooden Sword', 'Small Potion', 'Nice hat']

var luigi = Object.assign(Object.create(Player), Inventory)
luigi.init('Luigi', 1)
luigi.items // ['Wooden Sword', 'Small Potion', 'Nice hat'] ?
// Should be ['Wooden Sword', 'Small Potion']
```

Comment: when you create mario can you pass in an empty object, to Object.assign `Object.assign({}, Object.create(...`

Comment: But how can i delegate upwards, if im just passing an empty obj? I just want them to share the initial state of 'items' property.

Comment: disregard that, look at my answer below, you prob saw it by now...

Comment: pretty helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Object.assign` does not assign a deep copied structure from source to target object. Thus `mario.addItem('Nice hat')` already changes `Inventory.items` that remains a shared reference of `mario` and `luigi`. A poor men's approach like `mario.items = Array.from(Inventory.items)` as well as `luigi.items = Array.from(Inventory.items)` right after creating each `Player` instance does already help. Writing a `createPlayer` factory that does encapsulate object creation, `Inventory` composition and "cloning"/copying `items` would be even better ...

```js
var Player = {
 init: function (name, level) {
  this.name = name
  this.level = level
 },
 getLevel: function () {
  return this.level
 }
}

var Inventory = {
 items: ['Wooden Sword', 'Small Potion'],
 addItem: function (item) {
  this.items.push(item)
 },
 removeItem: function (item) {
  var i = this.items.indexOf(item);
  if (i === -1) {
   return this.items.splice(i, 1);
  }
 }
}

function createPlayer(name, level) {
  var player = Object.assign(Object.create(Player), Inventory);
  player.items = Array.from(Inventory.items);
  player.init(name, level);
  return player;
}

var mario = createPlayer('Mario', 1);
mario.addItem('Nice hat');

console.log('mario.items : ', mario.items); // ['Wooden Sword', 'Small Potion', 'Nice hat']

var luigi = createPlayer('Luigi', 1);
console.log('luigi.items : ', luigi.items); // ['Wooden Sword', 'Small Potion']
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you very much dude, this answer is awesome! I've been struggling on this for days, and I just wanted to go away from OOP's/Class-based Languages to full Functional because of this neatness! Thanks again.

Comment: @AidenHyde ... Thank's  ... But your design is as object-oriented as can be and does not feature any aspect of functional programming.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable is `Invertory` but you're using `Inventory`to create. Typo